# When using a nested while loop with getline, the inner while loop won't run more than once

Tags: c++, getline

I'm using getline to read in information from a .txt file and create an adjacency graph with that information. The text file will always have as many lines as entries in each line, but that quantity is never known. So far, I have this:

```
string title = argv[1];

ifstream myfile(title);

string line;
string word;

stringstream ss;

if (myfile.is_open()) 
{
     while (getline(myfile,line)) 
     {
         ss << line; //this line was edited after the post, the problem                 //is the same.
         while (getline(ss, word, ',')) 
         {
            //do some stuff to word
         }
     }
}
```

The first while loop completes and reads every line from the file into line, and then every new line is read into ss successfully. But the inner while loop only runs once, the first time the outer while loop is running. After this, the while condition (`getline(ss,word,',')`) is false.

The formatting of the information in the test file is as follows:

> cities,Atlanta,Boston,Boulder,Cheyenne,Chicago
>
> Atlanta,0,-1,-1,-1,-1
>
> Boston,-1,0,-1,-1,982
>
> Boulder,-1,-1,0,-1,1130
>
> Cheyenne,-1,-1,-1,0,-1
>
> Chicago,-1,982,1130,-1,0

I really have no idea what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Changing to `ss<<line;` might do the trick.

Comment: I recommend modeling a structure based on a record of your input.  Overload `operator>>` in the structure to read in the columns/fields.  IMHO, this design is better than your attempt at reading in the columns using a loop.  Also, there are not a lot of columns, so your code may be more efficient by reading each field, rather than using a loop.

Comment: I believe you want to insert `line` to `stringstream ss`, change `>>` to `<<`. For more info visit (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to clean the stream state after reusing it.